# Custom Circular widgets design flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-design

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what is thé appropriate way to make this in flutter?

It should be responsive and memory friendly.

Thanks

Here is the Circle Design

[image]

I have tried to do it with custom
Painter but it was not as expected and also expensive with thé resource.

Comment: You can try with CliPath/ShapeBorder on Stack

Comment: This package might be helpful for you.
You can use [link](https://pub.dev/packages/morphable_shape) package.